# PHP communicate with program

Tags: c#, java, php, mysql, json

I'm currently planning on a project I want to work on. These are the steps:

1. User visits the website and searches for a name
2. PHP sends a command to a C# or Java program
3. Program sends JSON data back to the website
4. PHP saves data to MySQL and shows data to user

I'm trying to research what I need to do to make this work. I just need advice on what to search for to learn. How do I make PHP and the program communicate? Should I look into servlet? Any advice on doing the steps more efficient like making the program query the database instead.

Comment: try web services,language independent .

Comment: The PHP seems redundant here. C#/Java can do whatever it is that PHP is doing in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd prefer Web-Service for your situation. you can design a Web-Service method for C# or Java , these mechanism provides a platform for your PHP application ( or another applications ). the PHP application only call the Web-Service methods. WS method perform the search and return the result. then you can process the result and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do this by database. Make a java thread scheduler which seance a database table each time. Now whenever PHP receive a request then it will insert that request into database with a new flag, now Java thread which is sensing the database will pick the request from database and process that and after processing will put the response into database , now PHP can pick that response and send back to USER.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use shell_exec from PHP to communication with C# or Java

Please read [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) for using shell_exec